Magento 2.4 Issue: The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again
I'm using the magento 2.4. I have created the auto generated coupon but which is not worked.
Here, I've attached the images.Could you help me?

Initally I make sure the from & to date.
Then, I have tried by adding this in the coupon.phtml file
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="{{form_key}}"/>
Also run the following commands
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush


I just given "from date" only for the price rule.
In the cart price rules form page, we can see that either Stop Rules Processing or Discard Subsequent Rules.


Just set "Yes" for Stop Rules Processing/Discard Subsequent Rules.
Some existing coupon may affect your current coupon.


Make sure in the manage coupon codes tab, confirm either coupon is used or unused.

I've created the auto generated coupon using the below api.
$accessToken = 'ymuo1rkbggrh467tmtlk502hw9fd2v8z'
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        ])->post(
            'https://example.com/rest/default/V1/salesRules',
            [
                'rule' => [
                    "name" => "TESTCOUPON",
                    "website_ids" => [1],
                    "customer_group_ids" => [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    "uses_per_customer" => 1,
                    "is_active" => true,
                    "stop_rules_processing" => true,
                    "is_advanced" => true,
                    "sort_order" => 0,
                    "discount_amount" => 10,
                    "discount_step" => 0,
                    "apply_to_shipping" => false,
                    "times_used" => 0,
                    "is_rss" => true,
                    "coupon_type" => "SPECIFIC_COUPON",
                    "use_auto_generation" => true, // Setting auto-generation to false
                    "uses_per_coupon" => 1,
                    "from_date" => Carbon::now()->toDateString(),
                    "simple_action" => "by_fixed"
                ]
            ]
        );
        $actionRule = $response->json();

        // Make POST request to create autogenerate coupon by using rule_id
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->post('https://example.com/rest/default/V1/coupons/generate', [
            'couponSpec' => [
                'rule_id' => $actionRule['rule_id'],
                'quantity' => 5,
                'length' => 12,
            ]
        ]);

Finally, The coupon is working.Here, I attached the screenshot for your reference.

